# SQL Query: grab those without any number

Tags: sql

I have two tables

1. events
2. albums

I want to grab all events that doesnt have any entry in the table `albums`.

I know how to do it to get all that HAS entrys:

```
SELECT id, title FROM events e
INNER JOIN albums a ON (e.id = a.eID)
```

How can i do the exact opposite, so it list out all the events that dont have a row with their id in eID in albums?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT id, title 
FROM events e
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM albums a WHERE a.eid = e.id)
```

You can also `LEFT JOIN` and check for `NULL` but EXISTS normally runs quicker.

Answer (score 0):

I tend to use this approach:

```
select id, title
from events
where id not in (select id from albums)
```

There's also the outer join way:

```
select a.id, a.title
from events a left outer join albums b on a.id = b.id
where b.id is null
```

Comment: There should be a condition after `ON`, not simply `id`.